# thinking_sphinx connection via MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

Ubuntu 14.04 installation, with nginx, passenger and postgresql.  The following steps are run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation  _for allowing only localhost connection_
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

gem file has

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.1.4'
```

thinking_sphinx.yml  specifies

```
  mysql41: 9312
```

Running:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
```

proceeds correctly: `total 112 writes, 0.079 sec, 485.0 kb/call avg, 0.7 msec/call avg  Started searchd successfully (pid: 21644).`

`netstat -ltnp` shows only one searchd process

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9312          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21644/searchd
```

So one concludes that everything is a go... right? [nasty buzzer]

```
ThinkingSphinx::ConnectionError 
Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. 
Error connecting to Sphinx via the MySQL protocol. _nice... stated twice!_
Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Possible avenues for non-connection:

1. mySql-server root password not digested
2. nginx somehow impeding the connection

others?  how to verify/assert?

Comment: Are you trying to secure the MySQL-protocol connection to Sphinx? Or for a MySQL database that Sphinx connects to?

Comment: Securing the MySQL-protocol connection.  The database is postgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

While Sphinx implements the MySQL protocol for querying, it does not pay any attention to authentication, so Thinking Sphinx doesn't use those fields either. So I'm not sure if mysql_secure_installation is the right tool for the job - certainly, not if it's trying to use authentication to control access. If you don't want to allow external communication to Sphinx, can you just block the port?

Comment: I back-tracked uninstalled via `sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common sudo apt-get auto remove sudo apt-get auto clean`, reinstalled omitting `mysql_secure_installation`and including `sudo apt-get install sphinx search`  rebuild runs properly.  `whereis` returns `searchd: /usr/bin/searchd /usr/share/man/man1/searchd.1.gz`.  Am getting the same connect via MySQL protocol... So there is something incorrect upstream...

Comment: from development.sphinx.conf: `searched {  listen = 127.0.0.1:9312:mysql41` which is then confirmed by `sudo netstat -ltnp` => `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9312          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11164/searchd` in the listing however `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10274/mysqld` appears and I wonder whether this is kosher...

Comment: OK...  `sudo reboot` followed by a `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake ts:rebuild` to get the engine running created a proper working environment.  There is still a `968/mysqld` port occupied.  Any ideas why this would solve the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Building on Pat's observation the following got me running on Ubuntu 14.04 installation, with nginx, passenger and postgresql.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install sphinx search
```

Ensure gem file has

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.1.4'
# alternately with JRuby
gem 'jdbc-mysql',      '~> 5.1.28', :platform => :jruby
```

thinking_sphinx.yml  must specify

```
  mysql41: [port_number]
```

multiple search processes need distinct ports.
Configure, index and start via:

```
RAILS_ENV=[your_environment] bundle exec rake ts:rebuild
```

`sudo netstat -ltnp` should show the listen port as defined in thinking_sphinx.yml and rendered in config/[your_environment].sphinx.conf

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:[port_number]          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21644/searchd
```

Finally,

```
sudo reboot
```